# Почему-то пропадает ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

У меня есть LinearLayout - главный Layout. В него программно вставляется RelativeLayout, а в то же время в RelativeLayout вставляется ImageView. У меня программно добавляются RelativeLayout в зависимости от условия. Но проблема в том, что когда я добавляю третий RelativeLayout, то первый RelativeLayout удаляется. не знаю, в чём ошибка.

[image: картинка с кодом]

Comment: Может он его просто перекрывает ?

Comment: @SegreiUlanov Не знаю даже. Всё должно работать так: каждый ImageView идёт друг за другом.

Comment: Попробуйте задать разный background, и размеры чуть разный и вы должны увидеть, что второй перекрывает. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php

Comment: @SegreiUlanov Да вроде всё нормально. Сделал background у всех элементов, и ничего не перекрывается. Странно.

Comment: Зачем вообще RelativeLayout если картинки идут одна за другой?

Comment: @Эникейщик Потому что в будущем в RelativeLayout будут добавлены ещё элементы.